# CVE-2006-20001 Why is this named 2006

Tags: security, cve

just for my culture I always thougt that CVE was named with this convention : CVE-YEAROFPUBLICATION-ID+1, meaning that the 1st CVE of 2024 would be named CVE-2024-0001 but for this particular CVE it is named 2006, however Published: 2023-01-17Updated: 2023-09-08.
It concerns Apache HTTP Server 2.4.54 and earlier (Release of 2.4.54 is July 2022)

Thanks for my culture
Lucas

I expected the CVE to be named CVE-2023-XXXXX

Answer (score 2):

The vulnerability was initially described in a 2006 publication "*The Art of Software Security Assessment*", as mentioned on [Apache's security vulnerabilities page](https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html#2.4.55); the table in which this is mentioned reproduced below with my emphasis:

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Described in first edition of "The Art of Software Security Assessment" | **2006-10-31** |
> | Reported to security team | 2022-08-10 |
> | Update 2.4.55 released | 2023-01-17 |
> | Affects | <=2.4.54 |

This would correctly adhere to [CVE's established nomenclature process](https://www.cve.org/About/Process) (emphasis also mine):

> CVE IDs have the following format:
>
> ```
> CVE prefix + Year + Arbitrary Digits
> ```
>
> **The “Year” portion is the year that the CVE ID was reserved or the
> year the vulnerability was made public.** The year portion is not used
> to indicate when the vulnerability was discovered.